# How to get value of property from nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem about get value of property .
Let say I have array of objects that describe books in some store - `booksArr`
And its looks like `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`.

Each of them like: `{title:"Move able fest", author:"Heminguay",..., *imageLinks:{thumbnail:"http://...bla-bla...png", smallThumbnail:"http://...bla-bla..small.png"}*...}`

I transfer to child component first  element like:

`<Book data={bookArr [0]} />`

The question is - How I can get *thumbnail* property inside `<Book>` component ?

It's like some object or collection inside other object.

I've tried different ways:

`Console.log (this.props.data[0].imageLinks.thumbnails)`

`Console.log (this.props.data.imageLinks.thumbnails)`
`Console.log (this.props.data.map ((item)=>(item.imageLinks.thumbnails))`

None of them correct.

Thanks a lot for your help!

I

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.log (this.props.data[0].imageLinks.thumbnails)
```

This cannot work because this.props.data is actually an element and not the full array.

```
Console.log (this.props.data.imageLinks.thumbnails)
```

In this case fixing the typo from `.thumbnails` to `.thumbnail` should do the job.

Comment: I'm posted topic above without my code. I was not in front of my notebook.  I'm not sure, but I think -in my code it's `thumbnail` without _s_.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
console.log(this.props.data.imageLinks.thumbnails);
```

You're trying to access the `thumbnails` property, which doesn't exist - it needs to be `thumbnail`:

```
console.log(this.props.data.imageLinks.thumbnail);
```

And now it will work.